# How to stack an image above a drawing area in GTK

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gstreamer

I have a sample program that plays videos using gstreamer toolkit which sit on a gtk based gui. I wanted to put a border image above the video, cutting off some of it's edges to mask a few graphical corruptions and otherwise for better estethics.

I beleive the drawingArea always wants to sit on top. I tried to stack them inside a GtkFixed with the following code to no avail.

```
gdk_window_lower(gtk_widget_get_parent_window(pipez[0]->drawingArea));
gdk_window_raise(gtk_widget_get_parent_window(screenz[0]->video_border));
```

Can anybody help out? Thanks for any help beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

GtkLayout allows to stack things, but I'm not sure tht's the best thing to do. Maybe you should just use GStreamer to cut the video's corrupted borders.